# Apache rewrite NOR syntax

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Getting confused and stuck on syntax for a rewrite rule.

Need to allow for an 'NOR' (?) on a condition so that if not domainA and not domainB, then true. Something like ?

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domainA\.com && !^domainB\.com [NC]
```

Anyone know the correct syntax ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the "AND" is implicit with successive RewriteCond's, so:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domainA\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domainB\.com [NC]
```

Is the same as: NOT domainA.com AND NOT domainB.com.